# Prevent form from submitting with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So this is driving me nuts. This code,

```
$('#the_form').submit(function(e){
            alert("Submit!");

            return false;
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

should prevent my HTML form,

```
<form id="the_form">
                <input type="text" name="q" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
```

from refreshing the page, but it doesn't. Does anyone have insight on this?

Comment: No code is executed after `return` statement.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/G9JLG/1 it works as is, but yes, no preventDefault() needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function() {
    $('#the_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Submit!");
    });
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about document ready handler. this should be the issue.

Comment: @undefined i think you right, because `return false`, prevents form from submitting

Comment: @eicto Yes `return false === event.preventDefault() + event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Both the `return false` and the `preventDefault` should stop the form, only reason I could think of why it would'nt, would be a missing DOM ready function? On the other hand one does'nt really need both, and there's no good reason to stop the propagation of a form submit that has been prevented.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `return false` from your code, or putting it after `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just **remove** the `return` statement..

Also Make sure your code is encased in DOM ready Handler

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#the_form').submit(function(e){
         alert("Submit!");
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```